# Click cell/link on summary tab that takes me to different tab and changes value of slicer

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink, slicers

I have a Summary Tab with a list of different customers in it. I also have a "Dashboard" tab that is a dynamic/filterable dashboard with slicers. On this dashboard, you can select which customer you want to view via the Slicer, and the dashboard changes to that customer's data based on a data tab and formulas.

My question is: Is there a way to be able to click on a customer in the Summary tab and it take me to the dashboard tab with that particular customer selected within the slicer?

If so, how would I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Correct, if I understand the question. You'll need VBA.

Comment: Record a Macro - ie Switch On Macro Recording - then do what you want manually and stop the recording. It will create a Macro for you and that is a good starting point.